# Display Laravel Nova image from a polymorphic table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm using Laravel 8 with Laravel Nova v3.17 and I’m trying to store a single image in a morph table called "Images" and display it. I’m able to store it however, the issue is that I can't display the image in edit or show pages.
Also, I tried to use MorphOne function but it displayed the morph record ID only.
What's the best way to display an image in a morph relationship?

Here are my models:

**Category Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Image::class, 'model');
    }

}
```

**Image Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Image extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'model_type',
        'model_id',
        'path'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the parent model (it could be a product, category etc..)
     */
    public function model()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

**Category Resource Fields Function**

```
/**
     * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make(__('ID'), 'id')->sortable(),

            FieldsImage::make(__('Image'), 'path')
                ->store(function (Request $request, $model) {
                    return function () use ($model, $request) {
                        $model->image()->updateOrCreate(
                            [
                                'model_id' => $model->id,
                                'model_type' => get_class($model),
                                'path' => Storage::disk('public')->put('images/categories', $request->path)
                            ]
                        );
                    };
                })
            // MorphOne::make('Image', 'image', Category::class),



        ];
    }
```

Comment: Hey, did you find any solutions to this?